# Получить ближайшие дочерние элементы

Tags: javascript

Есть некая разметка:

```
<div class='a' id='parent-1'>
    <div class='b' id='child-1'></div>
    <div class='c'>
        <div class='b' id='child-2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='b' id='child-3'></div>
    <div class='a' id='parent-2'>
        <div class='b' id='child-4'></div>
        <div class='b' id='child-5'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Необходимо получить ближайшие дочерние элементы `.b` родителя `.a`.

Например, для родителя `#parent-2` должны быть получены `#child-4` и `#child-5`, а для родителя `#parent-1` только `#child-1`, `#child-2` и `#child-3`, исключая дочерние элементы вложенного родителя.

При этом вложенность элементов может быть любой глубины.

Желательна реализация на чистом JavaScript.

---

Моя текущая реализация на jQuery (Полагаю что есть решению лучше):

```
const A = $('.a#parent-1');
$(A).find('.b').filter((_, e) => $(e).closest('.a').is(A));
```

Comment: `parent.querySelectorAll('.b')`

Comment: @Дмытрык тогда выдаст все дочерние элементы. Даже те, которые принадлежать другому вложенному родителю.

Comment: согласен. Надо подумать)

Comment: так вроде `children` просто. `$('.a#parent-1').children('.b')`

Comment: ну, вообще, взять дочерние эл-ты в js можно как-то так: `document.getElementById("parent-1").childNodes`

Comment: @Сергей Мишин прочтите задачу внимательнее)

Comment: @InDevX прочтите задачу внимательнее)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже что сам нашел решение

```js
function getNearestChildrenList(parentId) {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll('.b')].filter(b => (b.closest('.a').id === parentId));
}

console.log(getNearestChildrenList('parent-1'));
```

```html
<div class='a' id='parent-1'>
    <div class='b' id='child-1'></div>
    <div class='c'>
        <div class='b' id='child-2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='b' id='child-3'></div>
    <div class='a' id='parent-2'>
        <div class='b' id='child-4'></div>
        <div class='b' id='child-5'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать сделать так. Создаёт результирующий объект с ключами в качестве id родителя (с любой вложенностью). Ну это на JS, без JQuery:

**UPD** дополнил код, согласно комментам

```js
let aCont = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
let childItems = {};
[...aCont].forEach(items => {
  childItems[items.id] = [...items.children].filter(item => {
    return item.id.indexOf('parent') === -1;
  });
});

console.log(childItems);
```

```html
<div class='a' id='parent-1'>
    <div class='b' id='child-1'></div>
    <div class='b' id='child-2'></div>
    <div class='b' id='child-3'></div>
    <div class='a' id='parent-2'>
        <div class='b' id='child-4'></div>
        <div class='b' id='child-5'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
let aCont = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
let childItems = {};
[...aCont].forEach(items => {
  childItems[items.id] = getChildNodes([...items.children]);
});

console.log(childItems);

function getChildNodes(parentItem) {
  let result = [];
  parentItem.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id.indexOf('parent') !== -1) return;
    if (!item.children.length) {
      if (item.id.indexOf('child') !== -1) {
        result.push(item);
      } 
      return;
    }
    result = result.concat(getChildNodes([...item.children]))
  });
  return result;
}
```

```html
<div class='a' id='parent-1'>
    <div class='b' id='child-1'></div>
    <div class='c'>
        <div class='b' id='child-2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='b' id='child-3'></div>
    <div class='a' id='parent-2'>
        <div class='b' id='child-4'></div>
        <div class='b' id='child-5'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: При такой разметке - да, работает. Но, как я указал в посте, вложенность элементов может быть разной. Например `#child-2` может быть обернут еще каким-нибудь элементом и в таком случае записан в массив он не будет.

Comment: Для примера обновил разметку в главном посте.

Comment: @EssleJaxcate ок, спасибо, сейчас подумаем. Просто про вложенность подумал что может быть внутри только дивы с классном `a` и id `parent-...` на бесконечную глубину! а не с рандомными классами еще)

Comment: @EssleJaxcate дополнил ответ. Просто через рекурсию определяем и соединяем массив с разделением на родителей и проверкой является ли элемент тем который нам нужен в принципе!

Comment: спасибо, но я решил просто перевести свой вариант на чистый JS. Получилось в одну строку)